# How to get header from grpc responce with python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc-python, protobuf-python

I am trying to get header of the gRPC response with the following code, and it doesn't work:

```
response = stub.GetAccounts(users_pb2.GetAccountsRequest(), metadata=metadata)

header = response.header()
```

This is what this header looks like in Kreya, I'm trying to get it in python:

[image: Header in Kreya]

Does anyone know how to get the same header in python?

Comment: I suspect (! don't know) that you can't access the underlying HTTP/2 (response) headers from the (Python) gRPC client. You can configure various environment variables that expose underlying details (see [variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md)) and perhaps `GRPC_TRACE="http" GRPC_VERBOSITRY="DEBUG"`. If the headers were actually gRPC metadata, you can use Python's `with_call` and `call.initial_metadata` and `call.trailing_metadata` as shown [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/metadata/metadata_client.py)

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes, thanks a lot, using of with_call and call.initial_metadata is helped me

Comment: Great! I'll make the comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect (! don't know) that you can't access the underlying HTTP/2 (response) headers from the (Python) gRPC client.

You can configure various environment variables that expose underlying details (see [gRPC environment variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md)) and perhaps GRPC_TRACE="http" GRPC_VERBOSITRY="DEBUG".

If the headers were actually gRPC metadata, you can use Python's `with_call` and `call.initial_metadata` and `call.trailing_metadata` as shown in the gRPC metadata example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/metadata/metadata_client.py).